# How to find matches in a data table in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have one assigment.

[image: assigment]

Question: Do someone know an easy solution? I found no way to solve the question.

```
Try it: 

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Employees;
GO

CREATE TABLE #Employees
(
EmployeeID  INTEGER,
License     VARCHAR(100),
PRIMARY KEY (EmployeeID, License)
);
GO

INSERT INTO #Employees VALUES
(1001,'Class A'),
(1001,'Class B'),
(1001,'Class C'),
(2002,'Class A'),
(2002,'Class B'),
(2002,'Class C'),
(3003,'Class A'),
(3003,'Class D');
GO
```

My try but it does not work. Do someone have good idea?

```
SELECT * 
FROM #Employees as e1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * 
            FROM #Employees 
            WHERE 1 = 1 
              AND EmployeeID = 2002 ) as e2   ON e1.License = e2.License
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * 
            FROM #Employees 
            WHERE 1 = 1 
              AND EmployeeID = 3003 ) as e3   ON e1.License = e3.License
WHERE 1 = 1 
  AND e1.EmployeeID = 1001
```

Comment: its works. I like the String_AGG version. Its shorter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your version of SQL Server supports `STRING_AGG` function (*SQL Server 2017 (14.x) and later*), you may perform two levels of aggregation as the following:

```
SELECT EmpLic, STRING_AGG(EmployeeID, ',') AS EmpsWithSimilarLic
FROM
(
  SELECT EmployeeID,
       STRING_AGG(License, ',')  WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY License) AS EmpLic
  FROM #Employees
  GROUP BY EmployeeID
) T
GROUP BY EmpLic
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/qIZm4326).

Comment: Its a great and short idea. I have improve it, now the code is shorter.

Answer (score 0):

```
  with cte as (

  SELECT EmployeeID,
       STRING_AGG(License, ',') 
       AS lic_agg
  FROM Employees
  GROUP BY EmployeeID ) 

  SELECT STRING_AGG(EmployeeID, ',') as Matches
  FROM cte
  GROUP BY lic_agg
  Having COUNT(*) > 1
```